# What are the 3 arguments to Resolvers::ObjectSearch.call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, graphql

I'm looking at this test file as a reference to write my own https://github.com/howtographql/graphql-ruby/blob/master/test/graphql/resolvers/links_search_test.rb and I don't know what the arguments in `Resolvers::LinksSearch.call(nil, args, nil)` are. Are they, in order, `object`, `field`, and `context`? Like when you call `Mutations::CreateObject.new(object: nil, field: nil, context: {})`? I'm asking because I need to pass in the `current_user` in `context` and I'm not sure where I would do that for `Resolvers::LinksSearch.call`

Answer (score 0):

The argument order is `object:, context:, field:` and can be seen in the underlying GraphQL gem [here](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/master/lib/graphql/schema/resolver.rb#L34). `GraphQL::Schema::Resolver` is the base class used by `Resolvers::LinksSearch`

Additionally you can check out the Constructor details in the API documentation for [`GraphQL::Schema::Resolver`](https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/1.12.12/GraphQL/Schema/Resolver.html)